# MPI support in Python

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I was searching for MPI support in Python. I found out `mpi4py` is the only library exists for message passing interface in Python. Since I used to program MPI in C language, I want to ask how close `mpi4py` is from MPI library in C? Do you think it is slower? Is it the only library exists in Python?

Thank you

Comment: Did you have a look at the documentation of mpi4py? It mentions alternatives and how they differ from mpi4py: http://mpi4py.scipy.org/docs/usrman/intro.html#related-projects